# Ruby On Rails Nested Controllers: create model trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller

I have nested controller Reviews under Users, both generated by scaffold generator; view/index actions works well, but when I'm trying to create model (/users/1/reviews/new) there is an error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"reviews", :user_id=>#<Review id: nil, user_id: nil, reviewer_id: nil, predisposition: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

I've tryed to change form_for @review to form_for user_reviews_path(@review), but there is the same error on *create* action.

How can I fix this trouble?

Also I'd be grateful if you suggest me book about Ruby On Rails recipes (I've read ROR recipes from pragmatic, but it is too simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@review = @user.reviews.build(<enter your initialization params here>)
```

In your view:

```
=form_for [@user, @review] do |f|
```

I would start with the excellent http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and of course http://railscasts.com

Comment: One more trouble, in index action when there are any record is Routing Error, trouble becomes from %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_review_path(review). What is wrong? Routes looks like   resources :users do
    resources :reviews
  end
Thanks.

Comment: When you are editing an existing nested resource, you need to tell the router about both the object and its parent - in this case the user and the review.  So you need: edit_user_review_path(user, review)